# Setting all elements border, that have a data that is set to "yes"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this series of icons where I can select and set their border. I am limiting the number of chosen icons to 5. The first selected would become a yellow border one. The next 4 would be black border. When I click them again they need to be unset. I use the `.data` method:

On document.ready, I do:

```
$('img.selectable').click(function(){
    image_click(this);
});
```

For the CSS:

```
.selectable {
    border: 3px solid #ebe6b3;
    float:left;
    margin:1px;
}
```

For the HTML:

```
<img class="selectable" src="img/first_icon.png">
```

I have this function:

```
function image_click(e)
{
    if($(e).data("clicked")=="yes")
    {
        images_selected--;
        $(e).data("clicked","no").css('border','3px solid ' + NEUTRAL_COLOR);
        if(images_selected==1)
        {
            // PROBLEM HERE
            $(e).data("clicked==yes").css('border','3px solid ' + YELLOW_COLOR);
            // PROBLEM HERE
            // How do I set the remaining img elements with data 
            // "clicked"=="yes" to be YELLOW?
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (images_selected<5)
        {
            images_selected++;
            if(images_selected==1)
            {
                $(e).data("clicked","yes").css('border','3px solid ' YELLOW_COLOR);
            }
            else
            {
                $(e).data("clicked","yes").css('border','3px solid ' + BLACK_COLOR);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select the images, use the [`not()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude the clicked one, and then use the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter in the remaining ones that have `"yes"`.

```
$('img.selectable').not( e ).filter(function() {
    return $( this ).data("clicked")=="yes";
}).css('border','3px solid ' + YELLOW_COLOR);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kXCEr/1/

---

**EDIT:** Although I would tend to implement it like this, so you don't need to use `.data()`:

```
var NEUTRAL_COLOR = "#ebe6b3";
var YELLOW_COLOR = "yellow";
var BLACK_COLOR = "black";

var selected = [];

var imgs = $('img.selectable').click(image_click);

var updateColors = function() {
    $(selected[0]).css('border', '3px solid ' + YELLOW_COLOR);
    $(selected.slice(1)).css('border', '3px solid ' + BLACK_COLOR);
    imgs.not(selected).css('border', '3px solid ' + NEUTRAL_COLOR);
}

function image_click(e) {
    var idx = $.inArray(this, selected);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        selected.splice(idx, 1);
    } else if (selected.length < 5) {
        selected.push(this);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    updateColors();
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SJDxR/

This just maintains an Array of the selected items, modifies the Array when one is clicked (if there are fewer than 5), and updates the colors.

The element at the beginning of the Array is the first one clicked. If the previous "first" one is clicked again, it is spliced away making the second item in the Array the new "first", so it gets the yellow border.